# crystal reports detail display order in same order as user entered parameters

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

Crystal Reports Question.  I have a user who is entering in a list of invoice numbers into a parameter.  She wants to display the invoice number and other information in the order that she entered the list of invoice numbers into the parameter.  Is this possible in Crystal Reports.  I have seen a number of ways to do this in SQL, but not in Crystal Reports.

Below is a simplified version of the current SQL query used as a command in Crystal Reports.  The paramater {?InvoiceNumber} is a CR array parameter.

```
SELECT
     CUS.ACCOUNT,
     CUS.ADDRESS,
     CUS.COMPANY,
     INV.INVOICE_ID
FROM
     INV
INNER JOIN
     CUS
     ON INV.ACCOUNT = CUS.ACCOUNT
WHERE
     INV.INVOICE_ID IN {?InvoiceNumber}
```

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: I’ve tried to find out how the entered information is stored in the parameter, but as best I can tell this is random.  I’m wondering if the is a way to “label” the invoice numbers as they are entered, such as A-1987665, B-1876543, etc.

Comment: Have you tried to group using parameter?

Comment: @Siva I think group will not work, because the desired criteria is the order that the user entered the data. And he states that Crystal does not keep that order.

Comment: @SMcHugh How does the user enter the parameter values? Does he use the Crystal Report prompt or there is an input form?

Comment: @Siva But is it possible to group by the parameters? Or am i misunderstanding it? And how to use SpecifiedOrder? Would not it be necessary to previously know the possible values (like constants)?

Comment: @heringer My bad.. I am sorry just checked we can't group by parameter, Today I am busy will provide solution by tomorrow. Its been over an year worked on Crystal which led me to get confused. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas.  The grouping will not work.  Let me try to explain more.  The user is entering in a list of invoice numbers.  She is entering them in the order that she received an external document, and wants the Crystal Report detail to show the information in the same order so she can compare the two reports.  The list of invoice numbers changes daily, are not in sequence or order of any kind.  In order to create a group order, I would need to know the sequence or order of what she is entering (which I do not).

Comment: How does the user enter the list of invoice numbers?  Through the Crystal Reports prompt?

Comment: do you use sql-server?

Comment: The user enters the invoice numbers into a CR parameter prompt.  Yes, I uses SQL server.

Comment: @SMcHugh tried for few hours but unfortunately couldn't comeup with any solution that helps you. May be other experts will be able to help you

Comment: @heringer  Here is a thought...If I ask the user to provide a sequence (order) number with the invoice number as she enters them, perhaps this could help?  I'm thinking she could enter 1-123500, 2-321800, 3-464500...and so on.  Now, once these items are in the CR array parameter, I need to parse the invoice numbers out of the array and pass them to the SQL command (where invoice number in ({?Parameter}) will not work with the sequence numbers attached to them.  I also need to parse the array to get the sequence to use in CR as the sort by field.  Any ideas?

Comment: May you edit your question and add your query? I have an idea but it's easier to show in the query than to try to explain - and with the query i will see it if works.

Comment: @heringer Thanks again for the help and thoughts.  I posted an example of the CR command code (SQL) to show you what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a formula in Crystal Reports to find the invoice index in the parameter array. Let's name it IndexOf and the code could be:

   ```
   numbervar size:=ubound({?AccountNumber});
   numbervar position:=0;
   Local NumberVar i;
   For i := 1 To size Do
   (
       if {?AccountNumber}[i] = {INV.INVOICE_ID} 
       then position:=i;
   );
   position; //return
   ```
2. Create a group by IndexOf.

[Here is a shared RPT file working with this.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gzfAaUcSaqvUtjmL4pNzntkBMm9lKEYM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have done same but I ended up using either `{?AccountNumber}[i]` or `{INV.INVOICE_ID}` but not `position`... great thought. +1

Comment: @heringer  Thank you so much.  That worked.  It appears that when you enter the invoice numbers into the parameter, they keep their position in the array even with refreshing the report.  For my learning, can you explain why the //return at the end of your code?

Comment: It is just a comment to make it clear that the last line defines what the function returns ("position"). You can safely remove the comment "//return"